# Async load external webpack bundle

Tags: ajax, angular, asynchronous, webpack

I work with Angular 2 and Angular cli.
I want to load external module packaged with webpack.

I have try do it with Ajax and eval, but this doesn't work. My app and the external module have the same dependencies to Angular, this doesn't work.

I must dynamically load the module, because I can't know on build which module will be used.

Someone have an idea to load a webpack js file, on ajax?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am trying to do the same thing with angular 4.  The external webpacked ngmodule won't compile.